# Update ReadOnly Property during EventsPublishedContent

Tags: c#, episerver

First, I want to add a readonly type property to my page type, is this possible? 
What I want is a string property that can be updated programatically, but not through the UI, and I would like the content editor to be able to see the value but not change it.

Assuming that is possible how do I update this property value during the Publish Event.

So how do I...

```
private void EventsPublishedContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Content is MyPageType)
    {
         var myvalue = BusinessLogic.PerformAction(e.content)

         // Now I want to save myvalue on to a property in 
         // e.content.myProperty
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please don't ask multiple questions on the same topic on stackoverflow

**ReadOnly**

Readonly properties are created using either the `[ReadOnly(true)]` or `[Editable(false)]` annotations.

**Events**

What you are looking for is the [PublishingContent event](https://world.episerver.com/documentation/Class-library/?documentId=cms/7/5afd39c1-8d29-68eb-34a7-c5d3325f9ba2). There are many ways to configure this

Most basically need to tell Episerver in an initialization module that you want an event connected to a specific action on a specific IContent-type.

[From Episerver World](https://world.episerver.com/forum/developer-forum/-Episerver-75-CMS/Thread-Container/2014/5/Eventhandling/)

```
[InitializableModule]
[ModuleDependency(typeof(EPiServer.Web.InitializationModule))]
public class ContentEventHandler : IInitializableModule
{
    public void Initialize(InitializationEngine context)
    {
        var eventRegistry = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<IContentEvents>();

        eventRegistry.PublishingContent += OnPublishingContent;
    }

    private void OnPublishingContent(object sender, ContentEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Content.Name.Contains("BlockType"))
        {
            e.Content.Name = e.Content.Name.Replace("BlockType", "NewName");
        }
    }
}
```

Now this is ofcourse very primitive, typically I implement [Alf Nilsson's EPiEventHelper](https://github.com/alfnilsson/EPiEventHelper). This way you will get a generic way to implement the event handling

Snippet from https://talk.alfnilsson.se/2017/01/11/episerver-event-helper-v3-0/. This is also where you can learn more about the event helper

```
[ServiceConfiguration(typeof(IPublishingContent))]
public class PublishingStandardPage : PublishingContentBase<StandardPage>
{
    protected override void PublishingContent(object sender, TypedContentEventArgs e)
    {
        // Here you can access the standard page
        StandardPage standardPage = e.Content;
    }
}
```

Comment: Duplicate was a mistake, F5 - Comprehensive answer, thanks.